# symfony/config arrayNode prototype addDefaultsIfNotSet

Tags: php, symfony

I'm sorry to say I can't find a way to add a default value to a "symfony/config": "2.6.4" ConfigurationInterface !

What's wanted is this type of config :

```
X:
    Y:
        - test
        - testing
```

With default to :

```
X:
    Y:
        - test
```

By "default" I mean : if Y config branch is not set on the read configuration file, the $processor->processConfiguration should add it (and it does ! If I remove the ->prototype...)

Here is my code :

```php
class Definition implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root("X");
        $rootNode
            ->children()
                ->arrayNode("Y")
                    ->addDefaultsIfNotSet()
                    ->info("Multiple values can be used")
                    ->cannotBeEmpty()
                    ->addDefaultIfNotSet()
                    ->defaultValue(array("test"))
                    ->prototype("scalar")
                        ->validate()
                        ->ifNotInArray(array("test", "testing"))
                            ->thenInvalid("Invalid value %s")
                        ->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ;

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

Sure, I read this question [Using the Symfony2 configuration class, how do I define an array node whose children don't have keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11937710/using-the-symfony2-configuration-class-how-do-i-define-an-array-node-whose-chil)

My current code implements this way as you can read, but it does not work, my code throws :

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidDefinitionException]
  ->addDefaultsIfNotSet() is not applicable to prototype nodes at path "X.Y"
```

Answer (score 2):

For reference, I finally got it via a variableNode, just a minute before hitting the wall with my head ;)

```
class Definition implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root("X");
        $rootNode
            ->children()
                ->variableNode("Y")
                    ->info("Multiple values can be used")
                    ->cannotBeEmpty()
                    ->defaultValue(array("test"))
                    ->validate()
                        ->always(function ($values) {
                            foreach ((array) $values as $value) {
                                if (! in_array($value, array("test", "testing"))) {
                                    throw new \Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidTypeException("Invalid value ".$value);
                                }
                            }
                            return (array) $values;
                        })
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ;

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

It seems there is no way to do this with an arrayNode ! But if one find how, please do not hesitate to answer, I'll be pleased to accept the answer using arrayNode, as integrated validation is probably better than mine...

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
<?php
    $rootNode
        ->children()
            ->arrayNode("Y")
                ->defaultValue(array("test"))
                ->prototype("scalar")
                    ->validate()
                    ->ifNotInArray(array("test", "testing"))
                        ->thenInvalid("Invalid value %s")
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ;
```

Another question is, why not restructuring the config. You want a list of `test` or `test, testing` or `testing`. Why don't you configure it like:

```
X:
  Y:
    test: true
    testing: false
```

With `X.Y.test = true` by default and `X.Y.testing = false`? Then your `Configuration` would be very easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so:

```
$node
    ->fixXmlConfig('driver')
    ->children()
        ->arrayNode('drivers')
            ->scalarPrototype()->end()
        ->end()
    ->end()
;
```

This allows:

```
drivers: ['mysql', 'sqlite']
```

More info here
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html#array-node-options